# search by spliting the content of attributes in model -rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model `Lodging` which has an attribute `price_range`  this attribute contains data in this format `89;149` (in string format) say this is price range between 89 to 149 now I want to search those `lodgings` which have price range between `100-200` I want to do this by a single line query Like as `Lodging.where(...` is there any way which can solve my query?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you change the db structure?

Comment: No, I can't change the db structure.

Comment: Can you add tables to the database or create an additional supporting database, relational or otherwise?

Comment: Also… how many rows (rough order of magnitude) do you expect to be dealing with?

Comment: I can't change any db structure and there may be millions of rows in future

Comment: In that case, I believe that you have an impossible problem. Are you sure there is no kind of supporting database that you can create? An additional MySQL or PostgreSQL database, a Redis database? How is it that you are responsible for writing code in a Rails application and have no ability to modify the db? That's kind of like being responsible for maintaining a car without the ability to replace parts.

Comment: I'm already using Postgresql @SteveJorgensen

Comment: And also I would like to tell you that I'm learning Ruby on Rails ,I have not so much hands on Rails  @SteveJorgensen

Comment: @JaiKumarRajput why is the database structure fixed? What's the reason you can't change it? What's preventing you from adding an additional table?

Comment: @Stefan  I can add more table but can't change in this same table which has price_range field.

Comment: @JaiKumarRajput could you clarify that restriction, please? Why is it that you can't change the table?

Comment: Actully this project is a big project and this table is base table if  I will make any change this will increase more work to update the change in whole project thats why I don't want to change any thing in this table.

Comment: Even if it is more work now, it's probably worth the effort in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but that's a bad database design. I suggest to migrate your implementation to use two db fields (may be: low_price, high_price). Then you could do a search with a single query.

```
Lodging.where(["low_pric >= ?" AND high_price <= ?], 100, 200)
```

May be for you the following could work with MySQL, but I'm not shure. I can't test it at the moment:

```
Lodging.
  where(["(CONVERT(SUBSTRING(price_range, 1, LOCATE(';',price_range) -1) USING INTEGER) >= :low_price AND CONVERT(SUBSTRING(price_range, 1, LOCATE(';',price_range) -1) USING INTEGER) <= :low_price) OR (CONVERT(SUBSTRING(price_range, LOCATE(';',price_range) + 1) USING INTEGER) >= :high_price AND CONVERT(SUBSTRING(price_range, LOCATE(';',price_range) + 1) USING INTEGER) <= :high_price)", {:low_price => 100, :high_price => 200}])
```

Comment: I can't change the db structure thats why I asked here for help :) @guitarman

Comment: This has the same problem as @jaehyun-shin's proposal. It only handles the case where the entire range stored in the records is completely contained within the desired range.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend to split db column or to change the column type(range! if you use postgresql)

There is no rails style query. you must use DB QUERY IN where clause.

like(postgresql),

```
Lodging.where("cast(regexp_split_to_array(price_range, ';')[0] as int) > 100").where("cast(regexp_split_to_array(price_range, ';')[1] as int) < 200")
```

Comment: That won't handle cases in which the requested range overlaps the record's range. Unfortunately, you need to ask whether the given range contains either the lower or upper bound in the record, and also ask whether the range in the record contains the lower desired bound (in case the entire requested range is contained within the range in the record. This is a situation better handled using a dimensional database schema.